# Windows events for 3D mouse

Tags: c++, windows, mouseevent

I am developing a Windows application that must respond to events of 3d mouse, such as the 3DConnexion mouses, for example.

We have added support for 3DConnexion mouses using their dlls and libraries in C++, and it works properly. Now we would like to extend this support to any such device.

What I want to know is if there is a standard Windows support for these devices (via, for example, responding to Windows messages, like normal mouse events) or if I should give specific support for each type of mouse, loading the corresponding DLLs.

The latter would be rather unpleasant, because a separate library for each device should be used. I note that Google Earth, Photoshop and other applications respond to 3DConnexion events, and I gess they will respond to other 3d mouses. In this case, I doubt Google uses that cumbersome technique, and that makes me suspect that there must be a general mechanism, just as there is for the "normal" mouse.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: "I doubt Google uses that cumbersome technique"  Why do you think that?